# Changing the static IP of Beagle Bone Black USB0

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboard, beagleboneblack, debian-based

My goal is to change the IP address of `USB0`. 
The Beagle Bone Black run Debian.

I tryed to change `/etc/network/interfaces` such that default address is `192.168.7.3` instead of `192.168.7.2` as this:

```
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

After running

```
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

It was still on `192.168.7.2`.
I tryed rebotting, and yet is to no avail.

I tryed to change the IP address in `/boot/uboot/scripts/setup-ubuntu-armhf-3.8.13-bone30.sh`, but basicly this file overwrites `/etc/network/interfaces`.
Still after reboot the IP is still `192.168.7.2`.

**Edit:**
Also tryed to change the IP in:

```
/media/Angstrom/usr/bin/g-ether-load.sh
/media/Angstrom/etc/udev/rules.d/udhcpd.rules
```

Which didn't work.

Tryed to change it in:

```
/opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh
```

And now the network is unreachable:

```
 ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.3 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Have you tried the steps described by Eric Wong: ["Changing usb0 IP address on the BeagleBone Black"](http://ewong.me/changing-usb0-ip-address-on-the-beaglebone-black/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem on:

BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2017-03-19

The issue turned out to be "connmand" (read it again, it starts with coNN, not comm).  It is a horribly named program as it is difficult to research as Google assumed you spelled something wrong.

connman automatically configures wired instances for dhcp *despite* what is listed in /etc/network/interfaces.

Recommend either disabling it, or adding your interface to be ignored:

/etc/connman/main.conf:
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist=SoftAp0,usb0,usb1,eth0

After doing that and restarting, my static IP configured for eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces started working.