# Changing USB0 address of Beaglebone Black?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am trying to change the static IP address of USB0 port of BeagleBone Black.

I know this thread was open previously ([Changing the static IP of Beagle Bone Black USB0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805457/changing-the-static-ip-of-beagle-bone-black-usb0)). But no answer was found. So I am reopening now, to see if people have got any solution now.

I also found there is solution by Eric Wong. (http://ewong.me/changing-usb0-ip-address-on-the-beaglebone-black/) 
----- But this solution is good for may be old debian images. The latest ones have different file contents of what's mentioned in the solution. And therefore above solution does not work.

Steps I did:
step 1: I tried to change /etc/network/interfaces such that default address is 192.168.8.2 instead of 192.168.7.2 as this:

iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.8.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.8.0
    gateway 192.168.8.1

step2: Then I changed contents of file /etc/udhcpd.conf
-- change "192.168.7.1" to "192.168.8.1" in two places.

step3: reboot

Bingo, I lost my connectivity and now I have to rewrite the Debian image onto Beaglebone black again, as I no longer can access it. So basically neither I am unable to access through 192.168.7.2 or 192.168.8.2

So If anyone knows how to do it, It would be really helpful if you can share your thoughts ?

Comment: I had to change the settings on my host machine for the USB interface to make sure that it is on the new subnet.... I think 192.168.8.1 in your case. You may want to get a serial cable so that you can connect to the BBB even if the network settings are messed up. See :https://dave.cheney.net/2013/09/22/two-point-five-ways-to-access-the-serial-console-on-your-beaglebone-black

Answer (score 3):

Coming into this late; my network uses 192.168.6/24 and 192.168.7/24 internally, so the latest BB images didn't work for me at all.

First: there's no real substitute for a real serial connection via the J1 connector; a 3.3v USB serial doodad is cheap, and being able to watch the whole boot (and image flashing!) process from the very start is super helpful. Adafruit sells one that works great with BeagleBone: https://www.adafruit.com/product/954

Anyway, on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (Apr 2020 image), `/etc/default/bb-boot` contains:

```
...
USB_CONFIGURATION=enable
#It's assumed usb0 is always enabled, usb1 can be disabled...
USB0_SUBNET=192.168.7
USB0_ADDRESS=192.168.7.2
USB0_NETMASK=255.255.255.0

USB1_ENABLE=enable
USB1_SUBNET=192.168.6
USB1_ADDRESS=192.168.6.2
USB1_NETMASK=255.255.255.0

DNS_NAMESERVER=8.8.8.8
```

Adjust this to taste and reboot. In my case, I changed USB0 to 192.168.70, and #commented out all the USB1 lines altogether.

Because I have to re-flash a bunch of boards periodically, I burned this into the SD card image itself, which saved me a lot of time later.