# Connect two BBB to one PC using USB

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, serial-communication

My question is how to connect two BBB (Beagle Bone Black) into one PC using USB and communication with them at the same time.
I am trying to write a python script that two BBB boards to communicate with each other. The idea is that these boards should communicate with each other using iperf and an external cape (OpenVLC).
The problem is that I need to use the iperf on the server-side and then read the data on the client-side.
For this purpose, I need to connect them to one PC to be able to read commands and write the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
##USB_NETWORK_DISABLED=yes

###To Run Multple Boards on one USB HOST, change the 3rd octal on every
###USBx_SUBNET define and USBx_ADDRESS
###BeagleBone Number 2: USB0: 192.168.11.2 USB1: 192.168.10.2
###BeagleBone Number 3: USB0: 192.168.13.2 USB1: 192.168.12.2
###And So On..
```

This is from bb-boot on the images from rcn-ee.net/com.

Comment: I did not understand your reply. Could you please explain more? How can I change the IP?
Also, the link rcn-ee.net/com does not work. Could you please check it?

Comment: Hello...the link is not a link. It is a website address you can type in yourself to find different images from rcn-ee.net or rcn-ee.com.

Comment: So...now! We need to configure the IP Address. Okay. I will look that up but in the meantime, I suggest looking into this bbb ip-addr change yourself. So, we can relay info, both of us on the same page my help a bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404460/changing-usb0-address-of-beaglebone-black has an answer on it. Please look it over and read the article.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be a struggle. Both BBB grab the same IPs (192.168.6.2 and/or 192.168.7.2 depending on your PC's operating system) on their virtual Ethernet adapters and assign the same address to the PC side (192.168.6.1 and/or 192.168.7.1). You can change that in the startup scripts (google for details). Then you'd need to set your PC up to route traffic between the two which depends on your operating system. If you haven't done networking before, it's going to be hard.

Instead of USB, I'd strongly recommend connecting all devices to a simple router box using Ethernet. It just works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to networking. For connecting all devices to a router box, should I also do some settings on BBB side?

Comment: No. Just plug in the cable and it should be connected to network immediately.